# Tool to maintain/keep track of filesystem content integrity?

Tags: macos, filesystems, ntfs, checksum

I'm looking for a tool to maintain the integrity of a filesystem and it's contents using checksums. Effectively storing a list of checksums/filename pairs somewhere on the filesystem in a way that can be verified later if files are somehow damaged or lost.

Git does what I want, but because it stores the contents of every file in it's object database, the disk usage will at least double. And the fact that it does not provide a progress bar when scanning files tells me it was not designed for the multi-terabyte filesystem I have in mind.

I can do this crudely by storing the output of `md5deep`, but is there a tool specifically designed for this purpose, using whatever smarts possible to make the process efficient?

Comment: what filesystems/OS?

Comment: NTFS, Mac OSX .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

md5deep and related tools *are* in fact designed to verify file integrity. If MD5/SHA hash algorithms are too slow, it's because they were designed for cryptographic security first – if that is not required, CRC32 checksums are the next best choice. (For example, the Btrfs filesystem uses CRC32 for data integrity.) Search for "[SFV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_file_verification)" utilities (iSFV, MacSFV) that will automate the checking.